# echo quotes in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm creating an automatic network configuration script and in it i have

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo rm /etc/default/ifplugd  
sudo echo "INTERFACES=""
HOTPLUG_INTERFACES="wlan0 eth0"
ARGS="-q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I"
SUSPEND_ACTION="stop"" > /etc/default/ifplugd
```

however on viewing /etc/default/ifplugd some of the quotes are missing

```
INTERFACES=
HOTPLUG_INTERFACES=wlan0 eth0
ARGS=-q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
SUSPEND_ACTION=stop
```

How do I configure the script so it includes the quotes between the first and last echo ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `"` marks with a `\` prefix, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo rm /etc/default/ifplugd  
sudo echo "INTERFACES=\"\"
HOTPLUG_INTERFACES=\"wlan0 eth0\"
ARGS=\"-q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I\"
SUSPEND_ACTION=\"stop\"" > /etc/default/ifplugd
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
sudo sh -c 'cat <<END >/etc/default/ifplugd
INTERFACES=""
HOTPLUG_INTERFACES="wlan0 eth0"
ARGS="-q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I"
SUSPEND_ACTION="stop"
END
'
```

You don't need to explicitly `rm`, the `>` redirection will truncate the file before writing the new content.

Answer (score 1):

A *heredoc* provides an elegant solution:

```
sudo tee << EOF /etc/default/ifplugd
INTERFACES=""
HOTPLUG_INTERFACES="wlan0 eth0"
ARGS="-q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I"
SUSPEND_ACTION="stop"
EOF
```

This way, you don't have to manually quote each and every `""` around, and you are not removing the `ifplugd` file, so you won't need to reset permissions after creating it.